# Android Canvas - Draw a line graph with a gradient whose color depends on the y value

Tags: java, android, gui

I'm looking mostly for feedback on a solution of mine. I want to create a pretty line graph where the color of the line is dependent on the Y value, and a change in color at `y=0`. A loose example of such a graph is:

[image]

I was wondering how this can be accomplished on Android using `Canvas`, `Path`s, etc. I'm currently using MPAndroidChart to handle most of the dirty work. My solution for the coloring part is shown below.

I'm wondering if there is either a simpler way to do this or more efficient method. The reason why I ask is because this code does live in the `onDraw` method which should be as lightweight as possible and I am creating a new `LinearGradient` on every draw which I feel like is very expensive. The reason why I do these calculations on every draw is because I allow the user to zoom in on the graph and scroll it, which means the screen coordinates can always change.

```
protected void drawCubicBezier(ILineDataSet dataSet) {
    ...
    // Get screen coordinates for min Y value
    MPPointD pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, minDy);
    minDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
    MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

    // Get screen coordinates for max Y value
    pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, maxDy);
    maxDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
    MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

    // Get screen coordinates for 0 value
    pixelForValues = trans.getPixelForValues(0, 0);
    float zeroDy = (float) pixelForValues.y;
    MPPointD.recycleInstance(pixelForValues);

    float range = minDy - maxDy;
    float zeroPointNormalized = Math.max((zeroDy - maxDy) / range, 0);

    linearGradient = new LinearGradient(
            0, maxDy, 0, minDy,
            new int[]{Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE},
            new float[]{0, zeroPointNormalized, zeroPointNormalized, 1f},
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    paint.setShader(linearGradient);
    ...
    mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, paint);
}
```

Comment: can you share me your all source code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793760/draw-a-linechart-gradient-fill-with-a-gradient-whose-color-depends-on-the-y-va